# How to add an incremental string to beginning of file using awk

Tags: linux, awk, increment

I am trying to add an increasing number to the beginning of each line in a file along with a string using awk.

Here is what I try to do:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for ( i=1 ; i <= 60 ; i++ ) print "\""i"\""  "\""$0 }'
    test1.vdf > test2.vdf
```

However doing this only gives me the number and ignores the string in the file.

Comment: Perhaps you originally confused yourself by reading your own title?

Comment: or `cat -n`, although `nl` has a number of useful options for things fancier than just numbering the lines...

Answer (score 2):

BEGIN is a "special pattern" which is only processed *before the first record*

If you shift your attempt to a more likely area, you'll find you don't need to "loop" as the standard process of "one-record-at-a-time" will be doing that for you.

Try this:

```
{
    print "\""++i"\"" "\""$0
}
```

I don't know if it is the output you want exactly, but it is mostly your code.

Comment: I know you're just trying to u se as much of the OPs code as possible so he can see the changes inyour code, but for the OPs benefit - you can just print NR instead of ++i.

Comment: Yes, that is an excellent idea, I was concerned about where the "60" came into it in the original. Even so, NR would be better for identifying an "overflow/shortage" (if such there was) rather than keeping its own count.